# passing values from one form to another form with in the same page in php

Tags: php, forms

I have 2 forms named form1 and form2 in a single php page.form1 contains one text box.form2 contains two text boxes with a submit button.I want to validate all the textboxes when ever submit button pressed.But I cannot access the textbox value in form 1.My code is given below.

```
<html><body>
<form name=form1 method=POST>
<input type=text name=f1_t1>
</form>
<form name=form2 method=POST>
<input type=text name=f2_t1>
<input type=submit name=sub1>
</form></body></html>


<?php   

if(isset($_POST['sub1']))
 {
 $name=$_POST['f1_t1'];
 echo $name;}    
?>
```

this code error as undefined variable f1_t1.Can anyone help please?

Comment: Why do you use 2 forms?One submit has the scope of its respective form

Comment: The first form actually contains 3 radio  buttons along with text box.When clicking on each radio button I want to display corresponding forms each of then has different number of text boxes etc..When submitting, all these values must be validated.

Comment: Sidenote: You really should quote elements in your form. `<form name="form1" method="POST">` and especially for inputs.

Comment: Then you need to use ajax to validate your other forms. When you have more than one form on page, and you send one of them, you will retreive only the submitted values. Another version, if you add hidden fields, and on submit, you fill those hidden field values.

Comment: Consider putting everything in a single form and displaying/hiding different parts of the form based on input. Remember a `<form>` doesn't have to have *just* `<input/>` tags within it -- you can fill it with all sorts of html.

Comment: The problem is occuring because you're outside the form to which you're using the submit button with. There's your answer, along with a few other recommendations already given.

Comment: I only see one textbox in the form two.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest putting everything in a single form, and displaying/hiding sections of it as necessary (for example, with jQuery and CSS).

As an example, you could do this:

```
<form>
<div id="part1">
<input name="t1" type="radio" value="v1" />
<input name="t1" type="radio" value="v2" />
</div>
<div id="part2" style="display: none;">
<input name="t2" type="text" />
<input type="submit" />
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: if I want to display div part2 what should be the value for display?instead of none?

Comment: For a div, you can use `display: block;`

Comment: In terms of learning more about HTML and CSS in general, consider some online courses. I've had a good experience with Code School (don't work for them, just used them before). Check out their html course at https://www.codeschool.com/paths/html-css

Answer (score 0):

Only the fields in one form are submitted.
If for some reason you need to get the falues from a second form, you need to do that before posting, that is, on the client side. You could for example use javaScript to read the value of the field from the first form, write it to a hidden field in the second, and then post that to the server.

Comment: how to assign the values to form2 elements?cannot acces form 1 elements

Comment: The simplest way to do that with javaScript would be to add an ID to each form and then call
`fieldValue = document.getElementById('firstFormID').myFieldOfInterst.value`
You need to call a javaScript function `onSubmit` to do that.
The question remains why you would want to use two forms in the first place.